# Conditional Logic by Page number

Tags: cognito-forms

I have an issue where my "Thank you for your order!" content boxes (there are two, one for each type of order) both show up on the "Summary of entries" page after clicking submit.

If I could add a condition to those content boxes "Show only when before page X", I could have them disappear no matter what after a certain page of my form.

Is there any other way around this limitation?  Am I just blind?

Answer (score 0):

I work for Cognito Forms support.  If you have conditionals set up for each content box, then only the content boxes whose conditions have been satisfied should be showing on the entry details.  There's no conditional for specifying "only show on page x," however.

It might be best to [submit this as a support question](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support) and then we can take a look at the actual forms and what you want to achieve and see how to make that work.